# JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter due to quotes in value

Tags: python, json

I have a json input **content** that has escape characters (there are more entries, below is a sample)

```
{"invalid-input": "input isn\'t valid",
"enable-notifs": "\"Facebook\" would like to send notifs"}
```

When I directly do json.loads(content), I am getting Invalid \escape error. To fix this I ran the below code to replace all '\' with space.

```
content.replace('\\',' ')
```

But this is causing the quotes inside the value of "enable-notifs" to throw Expecting ',' delimiter error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you doing `.replace` on a dictionary? `content` is a dict, not a string which would be valid input for `json.loads`.

Comment: content is a json input i'm taking from a file, not a dictionary

Comment: Your escape `\'` is invalid in JSON.

Comment: Are there escape characters other than `\'` and `\"` in the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

You should not replace the \ with space. Instead you should properly format it to json string with json.dumps and then load it